# Property Content is null or is not IEnumerable

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a test page in Xamarin.Forms and it gets me this error, how can I fix this ?

> Property Content is null or is not IEnumerable

**Xaml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Project1.Page1">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Label Text="Page"></Label>
    <Editor Text="I am an Editor" />
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Why is Editor Title there ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `Content` property is of type `View`. You cannot have two views into it. Replace it with

```
<StackLayout >
    <Label Text="Page"></Label>
    <Editor Text="I am an Editor" />
<StackLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks but I had this error : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38099815/object-of-type-system-string-cannot-be-converted-to-type-xamarin-forms-view

Comment: Its okey now, I have seen that just leaving <!-- --> comment had gived me error.

Comment: Thank you..you saved my lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else lands here from google and the above wasn't the fix.  For me it was because I had a view with a `Grid.Row="0"` property set even though I accidentally placed it outside the bounds of the actual grid.