# Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'Xamarin.Forms.View'

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code and it gets me this error, how can I fix this ?

> Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'Xamarin.Forms.View'.

**Xaml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Project1.Page1">
    <ContentPage.Content>
      <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Text"></Label>
        Some text here
        <Editor Text="I am an Editor" />
      </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
  </ContentPage>
```

Comment: Please show your full XAML

Comment: Okey have updated.

Comment: Are you inheriting from ContentPage on your Page1.xaml.cs?

Comment: Please read my update

Comment: You should either: 1) include the problematic comments in your code above and then post/accept an answer that explains how you removed the comments and solved the problem; or 2) delete the question.  As written, and being unanswered, this really doesn't help anyone.

Comment: You are right, I have fixed the question now, thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This problem has solved when I removed the plain text that is inside the StackLayout. So I have changed it to a label component and have put the plain text in the text property.

This is the working code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Project1.Page1">
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
      <Label Text="Text"></Label>
      <Editor Text="I am an Editor" />
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Ah... after 2 hours trying to find a solution, I noticed that because of one ` character inside the `StackLayout` I was receiving this error... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Xaml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Project1.Page1">
    <ContentPage.Content>
      <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Text"></Label>
        <!--Some text here-->
        <Editor Text="I am an Editor" />
      </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
  </ContentPage>
```

Try to do this sir, this way change the text for comment

Regards